# Polynomials having all their zeros on the unit circle

Tags: cv.complex-variables, maximum-principle

Let $P(z)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^k$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ having all its zeros on the unit circle. Let $M=\max_{0\leq k\leq n}\lvert a_k\rvert$. The polynomial $P(z)=z^n+1$  has  $\max_{\lvert z\rvert=1}\lvert P(z)\rvert= 2$.  Intuitively, it appears that  $\max_{\lvert z\rvert=1}\lvert p(z)\rvert\geq 2M$.  Kindly share your opinion on the validity of this bound $2M$. Can it be further sharpened?

Comment: What about $1+z+... +z^n$?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. corrected it now.

Comment: See my comment to Conrad's post below.

Comment: @‍Conrad's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/457331) [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457291/polynomials-having-all-its-zeros-on-the-unit-circle#comment1184562_457291) by @GHfromMO, and their [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457291/polynomials-having-all-its-zeros-on-the-unit-circle#comment1184560_457331) on it.

Comment: The trivial lower bound is $\frac\pi 2M$. It is certainly not sharp and will improve to the desired bound $2M$ if we could show, for instance, that for every polynomial $P$ with the roots on the circle and maximal value $2$, we have $|\{|P|>t\}|\le|\{|z-1|>t\}|$ for all $t\in(0,2)$, which seems plausible but I have no proof at the moment :-).

Comment: The "Close" votes are not justified. Please do not vote to close this question, as it is clearly on topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result follows with $M=|a_n|$ actually as below:

Note that if $P$ has all the roots $w_j$ on the unit circle it follows that $w_j=1/\bar w_j$ so there is $c \ne 0$ st $$P(z)=cz^n\overline {P(1/\bar z)}=c\sum_{k=0}^n \bar a_kz^{n-k} $$ hence $a_k=c \bar a_{n-k}$ and in particular since $a_n \ne 0$ we have $a_0 \ne 0, |c|=1$ so $|a_0|=|a_n|$

But $a_0+a_nz^n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{\omega^n=1}P(wz)$, so $|a_0+a_nz^n| \le \max_{|\zeta|=1}|P(\zeta)|$ for all $|z|=1$ hence choosing $|z|=1$ st $|a_0+a_nz^n|=|a_0|+|a_n|=2|a_n|$ the result follows

Note also that we only used that $P$ is self inversive ($w_j$ root iff $1/\bar w_j$ root and no zero roots) and actually only that $|a_0|=|a_n|$ which is implied by self-inversivity.

Comment: The statement (in slightly sharper form) was the 2nd problem in the 1991 Schweitzer Contest in Hungary. See Problem G.47 in Székely (ed.): Contests in Higher Mathematics - Miklós Schweitzer Competitions (1962-1991).

Comment: So $|a_0|+|a_n|$ is a lower bound for all polynomials without any assumptions.

Comment: This is well known Visser’s inequality.

Comment: @user by using different roots of unity on $P$ but also on $zP$ and such as well as on the $z^n\bar P(1/\bar z)$ transform clearly one can obtain various similar inequalities as long as we can get rid of all but at most two terms so I am convinced this should be known, but it is easy to prove anyway; similarly the coefficient relation for polynomials with unit circle roots is well known

Comment: Visser's inequality has been generalized by several researchers (e.g. there was an immediate generalization by Visser and van der Corput), and Google finds many references. Visser's original publication is C. Visser: A simple proof of certain inequalities concerning polynomials, Nederl. Akad. Wetensch. Proc. 48, 276-281 = Indag. Math. 7 (1945), 81-86.

Comment: @GHfromMO The problem boils down (actually, is equivalent)  to the following innocently looking question: if $P=a_0+\Re\sum_{k=1}^n a_kz^k$ is a real trigonometric polynomial of degree $n$ with $2n$ zeroes on the unit circle. Then $|a_0|\le \frac 12\|P\|_\infty$ (or, in other words, the only case of interest is the inequality $\|P\|_\infty\ge 2|a_m|$ for algebraic polynomials $P$ of even degree $n=2m$ with complex coefficients and all zeroes on the unit circle). Have you seen this generalization of Visser anywhere?

Comment: @fedja I have not seen this generalization, but I am not familiar with this topic either. I usually cover Visser's inequality in the first week of my complex analysis class, but I did not know until this MO post that the result was due to Visser from 1945. I only knew the problem from the 1991 Schweitzer Contest.

Comment: @fedja the result is true but nontrivial with the equality cases determined (they are essentially coming from complex polynomials of the type $c(z^m+e^{ia})^2,  a\in \mathbb R$)    - not sure who proved this first but a (4 page) proof is presented in the comprehensive book Analytic Theory of Polynomials by Rahman and Schmeisser, Th $16.1.9$ pages 646-650; see https://global.oup.com/academic/product/analytic-theory-of-polynomials-9780198534938?cc=us&lang=en&

Comment: @Conrad Thanks. I'll still spend some time trying to figure it out myself before looking up the proof in the book and comparing it with the ideas I currently have but it is nice to know that the conjecture is known to be correct :-). BTW, once you know the literature so well, is it also well known what is the best constant in the Bernstein inequality $\|P'\|_{L^p}\le Cn\|P\|_{L^p}$ for *non-negative real-valued* trigonometric polynomials of degree $n$? I once figured out the case $p=1$ (the extremizer is $1+\cos nx$, of course), but I still don't know the truth for any other $p\ne2,\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer became outdated when the question was edited. Originally $2M$ was stated as an upper not lower bound, due to a typo. Watch your signs!*

Yup, as suggested by Fedor in the comments the premise is false. For example, $P(z)=z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1$ has all zeroes on the boundary of the unit disk and all coefficients unity, but $|P(1)|>2$.

If $z$ is inside or on the unti disk, then all polynomial functions (regardless of their zeroes) satisfy $|P(z)|\le\sum|a_n|$ from the Triangle Inequality.

Comment: It was a typo, a reverse bound is asked about